# Search for keywords

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Can anyone give me an idea of how i can improve my search system?

Right now i'm just comparing the word i type in my search box to the name of the object i want to find. But this way it has to be the exact same word.

I'd like to somehow have a list of keywords for each object, and if i hit that keyword in a search it'l pop up with the object i wanted to find.

I thought about storing my keywords in an array, but how would i add a word to an array?
I also had a thought on having all my keywords in an enum, is that possible? if so, how?

Comment: It's completely unclear to me what you're asking. Unity3D is for games, but I have a feeling your _search system_ is not in-game. Also, show some code.

Comment: Sorry. It's not exactly a game, but it's created inside Unity3D though. I'm creating a program where i have some objects stored in a list. And to acces them, i have a gui text field used to search my list for the object i want.

Now what i want, is for this object to have certain keywords attached to it, so that instead of typing the whole word such as for eksample "Pythagoras" i'd only have to type "pyt" or "pyta"

Comment: could you include some minimal script examples. If you mean you want it in the Editor I would guess you want to make a Custom Editor

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working the way i wanted. It may not be the best solution, but it works for what my needs are right now.

This is still a work in progress, and many things still need to be changed, but for now, the search function works, with keyword support.

Thanks to those of you who were quick to respond :)

For anyone looking to do the same thing, here's some code:

FormulaClass:

```
 #pragma strict
 import System.Collections.Generic;

 public class Formula
 {
    var name : String;
    var formula : Texture2D;
    var example : Texture2D;
    //This is where i put all the words i can search for, 
    //to find this particular object.
    var keywords : List.<String> = new List.<String>(); 
 }
```

FormulaContainer:

```
#pragma strict
import System.Collections.Generic;

var formulas : List.<GameObject> = new List.<GameObject>();


private var myTransform : Transform;


function Start () 
{
    myTransform = transform;

    formulas.Add(Resources.Load("Formulas/Pythagoras", GameObject));
    formulas.Add(Resources.Load("Formulas/Test2", GameObject));
    formulas.Add(Resources.Load("Formulas/Test3", GameObject));
}

function Search (searchWord : String) : GameObject
{
    var searchResult : GameObject;
    var formulaScript : FormulaScript;

    for (var formula : GameObject in formulas)
    {
        formulaScript = formula.GetComponent(FormulaScript);

        for (var keyword : String in formulaScript.formulaClass.keywords)
        {
            if (keyword == searchWord)
            {
                searchResult = formula;
            }
        }
    }
    return searchResult;
}
```

FormulaScript:

```
#pragma strict

var formulaClass : Formula;

private var myTransform : Transform;


function Start () 
{
    myTransform = transform;

    formulaClass.name = myTransform.name;
    formulaClass.formula = Resources.Load("Images/" + myTransform.name, Texture2D);
    formulaClass.example = Resources.Load("Images/" + myTransform.name + "Example", Texture2D);
}
```

UI:

```
#pragma strict

private var myTransform : Transform;
private var currentFormula : GameObject;
private var currentInstanceFormula : GameObject;
private var size : Vector2;
private var offset : int = 25;
private var searchField : String = "";
private var container : FormulaContainer;


function Start () 
{
    myTransform = transform;

    container = myTransform.GetComponent(FormulaContainer);

    size.x = Screen.width - offset * 2;
    size.y = Screen.height - offset * 2;
}

function OnGUI ()
{   
    GUI.BeginGroup (new Rect (offset, offset, size.x, size.y));

        GUI.Box (new Rect (0, 0, size.x, size.y), "");

        searchField = GUI.TextField (Rect (25, 25, 100, 25), searchField);

        if (GUI.Button (Rect (130, 25, 65, 25), "Search")) 
        {
            currentFormula = container.Search(searchField);

            if (currentInstanceFormula)
            {
                Destroy(currentInstanceFormula);
            }

            if (currentFormula)
            {
                Debug.LogWarning ("found " + currentFormula.transform.name + " during the search");
                var newInstance : GameObject = Instantiate (currentFormula, myTransform.position, myTransform.rotation);
                currentInstanceFormula = newInstance;
                newInstance.transform.name = currentFormula.transform.name;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogWarning ("Nothing was found during the search");
            }
        }

        if (currentInstanceFormula)
        {
            var formulaScript : FormulaScript;
            var name : String;
            var formula : Texture2D;
            var example : Texture2D;

            formulaScript = currentInstanceFormula.GetComponent(FormulaScript);
            name = formulaScript.formulaClass.name;
            formula = formulaScript.formulaClass.formula;
            example = formulaScript.formulaClass.example;

            GUI.Label (new Rect (25, 75, 100, 25), name);
            GUI.DrawTexture (new Rect (100, 150, 256, 64), formula);
            GUI.DrawTexture (new Rect (450, 150, 512, 256), example);
        }

    GUI.EndGroup();
}
```

Comment: +1 for sharing your results. I started an answer but dropped it when I saw the javascript tag (I understand it but readonly :) I can't see ignore case searching in your code, but I think this is pretty important.